# C - Ignore subdirectories names and only print files names

Tags: c, recursion, file-listing

With this code I'm able to print recursively all files and subdirectories from a given path.

What I want is to ignore (not print) all the subdirectorynames, and only print the file names.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h> 


void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath)
{
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);

    if (!dir)
        return;

    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);

            listFilesRecursively(path);
            printf("%s\n", path);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}

int main()
{
    char path[100];

    printf("Enter path to list files: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    listFilesRecursively(path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man 2 stat` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are macros that tells you what type of file it is:

- `S_ISREG()`: regular file
- `S_ISDIR()`: directory file
- `S_ISCHR()`: character special file
- `S_ISBLK()`:  block special file
- `S_ISFIFO()`: pipe or FIFO 
  -`S_ISLNK()`: symbolic
- `S_ISSOCK()`: link socket

First of all you can use one of the following functions to get informaration:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int stat(const char *restrict pathname, struct stat *restrict buf );
int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf);
int lstat(const char *restrict pathname, struct stat *restrict buf );
int fstatat(int fd, const char *restrict pathname, struct stat *restrict buf, int flag);
```

From the Advanced Programming in Unix Environment book:

> Given a pathname, the stat function returns a structure of information
>   about the named file. The fstat function obtains information about the
>   file that is already open on the descriptor fd. The lstat function is
>   similar to stat, but when the named file is a symbolic link, lstat
>   returns information about the symbolic link, not the file referenced
>   by the symbolic link.

You can try something like the following:

```
struct stat statbuf;
struct dirent *dirp;
DIR *dp;
int ret, n;
/* fullpath contains full pathname for every file */
if (lstat(fullpath, &statbuf) < 0)
{
    printf("error\n");
    //return if you want
}
if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) == 0)
{
   /* not a directory */
}
else
{
   //a directory
}
```

Historically, early versions of the UNIX System didn’t provide the `S_ISxxx` macros. Instead, we had to logically `AND` the `st_mode` value with the mask `S_IFMT` and then compare the result with the constants whose names are `S_IFxxx`. Most systems define this mask and the related constants in the file .

For example:

```
struct stat *statptr;
if (lstat(fullpath, statptr) < 0)
{
    printf("error\n");
    //return if you want
}
switch (statptr->st_mode & S_IFMT) {
    case S_IFREG:  ...
    case S_IFBLK:  ...
    case S_IFCHR:  ...
    case S_IFIFO:  ...
    case S_IFLNK:  ...
    case S_IFSOCK: ... 
    case S_IFDIR:  ... 
    }
```